# QWidget::paintEngine being called from QCoreApplication::processEvents

Tags: opengl, qt5, qtopengl

I'm converting an OSX application from Qt 4/Carbon to Qt5.11 with the QOpenGLWidget.

I've moved the drawing "calls" to my overridden QOpenGlWidget::paintGL().

The problem is I'm still getting these messages on the console:

QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called

Getting a stack trace, I've discovered that this is being called eventually from QCoreApplication::processEvents, which I'm calling from my own internal event loop.

Here's a stack trace (edited for readability)

- thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1

  - frame #0: libQt5Widgets_debug.5.dylib`QWidget::paintEngine()
    frame #1: libQt5Widgets_debug.5.dylib`QOpenGLWidget::paintEngine(0)
    frame #2: libQt5Gui_debug.5.dylib`QPainter::begin()
    frame #3: libQt5Gui_debug.5.dylib`QPainter::QPainter()
    frame #4: libQt5Gui_debug.5.dylib`QPainter::QPainter()
    frame #5: libQt5Widgets_debug.5.dylib`QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget()
    frame #6: libQt5Widgets_debug.5.dylib`QWidgetPrivate::repaint_sys()
    frame #7: libQt5Widgets_debug.5.dylib`QWidgetPrivate::syncBackingStore()
    frame #8: libQt5Widgets_debug.5.dylib`QWidgetWindow::handleExposeEvent()
    frame #9: libQt5Widgets_debug.5.dylib`QWidgetWindow::event()
    frame #10: libQt5Widgets_debug.5.dylib`QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper()
    frame #11: libQt5Widgets_debug.5.dylib`QApplication::notify()
    frame #12: libQt5Core_debug.5.dylib`QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2()
    frame #13: libQt5Gui_debug.5.dylib`QCoreApplication::sendSpontaneousEvent()
    frame #14: libQt5Gui_debug.5.dylib`QGuiApplicationPrivate::processExposeEvent()
    frame #15: libQt5Gui_debug.5.dylib`QGuiApplicationPrivate::processWindowSystemEvent()
    frame #16: libQt5Gui_debug.5.dylib`bool QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::handleWindowSystemEvent<QWindowSystemInterface::SynchronousDelivery>()
    frame #17: libQt5Gui_debug.5.dylib`void QWindowSystemInterface::handleExposeEvent()
    frame #18: libqcocoa_debug.dylib`QCocoaWindow::handleExposeEvent()
    frame #19: libqcocoa_debug.dylib`::-[QNSView updateRegion:](self=0x000061200039fc40, _cmd="updateRegion:", dirtyRegion=QRegion @ 0x00007ffeefbf9b18)
    frame #20: libqcocoa_debug.dylib`::-[QNSView updateLayer](self=0x000061200039fc40, _cmd="updateLayer")
    frame #21: AppKit`_NSViewUpdateLayer + 45
    frame #22: AppKit`-[_NSViewBackingLayer display] + 495
    frame #23: QuartzCore`CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 634
    frame #24: QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 319
    frame #25: QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 576
    frame #26: QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 66
    frame #27: CoreFoundation`**CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23
    frame #28: CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 452
    frame #29: CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 523
    frame #30: HIToolbox`RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 293
    frame #31: HIToolbox`ReceiveNextEventCommon + 618
    frame #32: HIToolbox`_BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
    frame #33: AppKit`_DPSNextEvent + 997
    frame #34: AppKit`-[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1362
    frame #35: libqcocoa_debug.dylib`QCocoaEventDispatcher::processEvents(this=0x00006040000dbdf0, flags=(i = 0)) at qcocoaeventdispatcher.mm:482
    frame #36: libQt5Core_debug.5.dylib`QCoreApplication::processEvents(flags=(i = 0)) at qcoreapplication.cpp:1252

The problem is that ::processEvents is eventually calling ::paintEngine for the QOpenGLWidget, OUTSIDE of ::paintGL, but it's totally out of my control.

FWIW, the Event driving this is a QEvent::UpdateRequest.

I tried overriding ::event in my QOpenGLWidget-inheriting class to call QOpenGlWidget::update when it receives a QEvent::UpdateRequest, but that just ended up making the app non-responsive.

How should I handle ::processEvents attempting to draw QOpenGlWidgets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by removing this statement from our QOpenGlWidget subclass:

**setAttribute( Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen, true );**

Removing this got ride of the paintEngine calls (and solved all kinds of other problems).

Comment: It's good to hear that you found the cause of your problem.  You could make your answer more helpful for future readers by explaining *how* you diagnosed it, and in particular, which evidence will identify this problem when it's seen elsewhere.

Comment: LOL. I "diagnosed" is by removing / commenting out calls one by one until it worked. Sometimes simple things work.